# Comparing two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have an array containing a list of cars, and an image URL.

On the page, i have a list of lots of cars. I want to loop over all cars on page, and if it is within the cars array, then I want to swap it's image to the new one.

What would be the best way to go about this?

```
<!-- example of on page list of cars -->

<li class="car" data-id="car1">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car12">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car2">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car7">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>
```

--

```
const cars = [
    {
        "id": "car1"
        "newImage": "imageaddress1"
    },
    {
        "id": "car2"
        "newImage": "imageaddress2"
    },
    {
        "id": "car3"
        "newImage": "imageaddress3"
    },
]

const allCarsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.car');
const allCars = Array.from(allProductsNodeList);
```

First thoughts are to use filter to reduce the on page cars down to only the ones featured, but I'm lost on how to do the comparison since in neither the array or the on page data-attribute are directly there.

I'm confused basically! Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the results in the node list and compare the data-id to the id of the cars array. If it matches - swap the src attribute to the newImage.

I am also updating the alt attribute so that you can see the src has changes (since I don't have your images)

```js
const cars = [
    {
        "id": "car1",
        "newImage": "imageaddress1"
    },
    {
        "id": "car2",
        "newImage": "imageaddress2"
    },
    {
        "id": "car3",
        "newImage": "imageaddress3"
    },
]


const allCarsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.car');

allCarsNodeList.forEach(function(car, index){
  var id = car.getAttribute('data-id');
  var image = car.querySelector('img');
  cars.forEach(function(carItem){
     if(carItem.id == id) {
      image.setAttribute('src', carItem.newImage);
      image.setAttribute('alt', carItem.newImage) ;
     }
   })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="car" data-id="car1">
      <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="currentImage">
  </li>

  <li class="car" data-id="car12">
      <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="currentImage">
  </li>

  <li class="car" data-id="car2">
      <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="currentImage">
  </li>

  <li class="car" data-id="car7">
      <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="currentImage">
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

- First create an object from `cars` array with `id` as key and image url as value
- Now, iterate over the array and see whether the element's id exist in the object created above. If it exists, update the `src` of corresponding `img`

```js
const cars = [{"id": "car1","newImage": "imageaddress1"},{"id": "car2","newImage": "imageaddress2"},{"id": "car3","newImage": "imageaddress3"}];
// Create a map of id and newImage
const obj = cars.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.id] : c.newImage}), {});
// Get all cars 
const allCars = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.car'));
// Iterate over cars
allCars.forEach(c => {
  //if entry exists in the object, update corresponding image
  if(obj[c.dataset.id]) c.querySelector("img").src = obj[c.dataset.id];
});
```

```html
<li class="car" data-id="car1">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car12">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car2">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car7">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Get all the elements with class `car`
2. Loop through that element and find the `data-id` value of each element
3. Use that `data-id` value to find a matching object in `cars` array
4. If a object is found then replace the `src` attribute of that image which is inside the `.car` element with the `newImage` value of the object.

```js
const cars = [{
    "id": "car1",
    "newImage": "imageaddress1"
  },
  {
    "id": "car2",
    "newImage": "imageaddress2"
  },
  {
    "id": "car3",
    "newImage": "imageaddress3"
  }
]

const allCarsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.car');
for (var i = 0; i < allCarsNodeList.length; i++) {
  var carId = allCarsNodeList[i].dataset.id;
  var matchCar = cars.find(({id}) => carId === id);
  if (matchCar) {
    allCarsNodeList[i].querySelector('img').src = matchCar.newImage;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="car" data-id="car1">1
  <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car12">2
  <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car2">3
  <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car7">4
  <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>
```

> Use `inspect element` on the output to check that the `src` attribute is actually changed by the value of the `newImage`

Answer (score 0):

This work for me :

```
    const allCarsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.car');
    const allCars = Array.from(allCarsNodeList);
    console.log(allCars)
    allCars.forEach(car => {
        carId = car.dataset.id
        correspondingCar = cars.filter(each => each.id === carId)[0]
        console.log(correspondingCar);
        if (correspondingCar !== undefined) {
            car.children[0].src = correspondingCar.newImage
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your cars are stored in an array with a unique id, I would recommend converting this cars array into a dictionary first (this will increase performance):

```js
const cars = [
    {
        "id": "car1",
        "newImage": "imageaddress1"
    },
    {
        "id": "car2",
        "newImage": "imageaddress2"
    },
    {
        "id": "car3",
        "newImage": "imageaddress3"
    }
]

// create cars dictionary from carsList
const carsDictionary = cars.reduce((r, car) => {
    r[car.id] = car;
    return r;
}, {});

// iterate over nodes with car class
const carNodesDict = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.car'))
.forEach((node) => {
    const car = carsDictionary[node.dataset.id];
    if (car != null) {
      node.querySelector('img').src = car.newImage;
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- example of on page list of cars -->

<li class="car" data-id="car1">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car12">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car2">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>

<li class="car" data-id="car7">
    <img src="https://imageurl.com/currentImage" alt="">
</li>
```